# Converting GeoJSON to DbGeometry

Tags: geojson, bing-maps

I am working on Bing maps, but fairly new to spatial data types. I have managed to get the GeoJson data for a shape from bing maps for example,

```
{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[30.86202,-17.85882],[30.93311,-17.89084],[30.90701,-17.92073],[30.87112,-17.90048],[30.86202,-17.85882],[30.86202,-17.85882],[30.86202,-17.85882]]]]}
```

However I need to save this as DbGeomtry in SQL, how can convert GeoJson to DbGeomtry

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1.** 
Convert the `GeoJSON` to `WKT` and then use [stgeomfromtext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stgeomfromtext-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) to create the `Db` object.

**Option 2.**
Deserialize the `GeoJSON` using [GeoJSON.Net](https://github.com/GeoJSON-Net/GeoJSON.Net) and then use the nuget package `GeoJSON.Net.Contrib.MsSqlSpatial` to convert to a `Db` object. eg.

```
DbGeography dbGeographyPoint = point.ToDbGeography();
```

**Option 3.**
For some types of GeoJSON data, modifications based on [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2016/01/05/loading-geojson-data-into-sql-server/) approach can be used

```
drop table if exists BikeShare
create table BikeShare(
           id int identity primary key,
           position Geography,
           ObjectId int,
           Address nvarchar(200),
           Bikes int,
           Docks int )
```

```
declare @bikeShares nvarchar(max) = 
'{"type":"FeatureCollection",
  "features":[{"type":"Feature",
               "id":"56679924",
               "geometry":{"type":"Point",
                            "coordinates":[-77.0592213018017,38.90222845310455]},
               "properties":{"OBJECTID":56679924,"ID":72,
                              "ADDRESS":"Georgetown Harbor / 30th St NW",
                              "TERMINAL_NUMBER":"31215",
                              "LATITUDE":38.902221,"LONGITUDE":-77.059219,
                              "INSTALLED":"YES","LOCKED":"NO",
                              "INSTALL_DATE":"2010-10-05T13:43:00.000Z",
                              "REMOVAL_DATE":null,
                               "TEMPORARY_INSTALL":"NO",
                              "NUMBER_OF_BIKES":15,
                              "NUMBER_OF_EMPTY_DOCKS":4,
                              "X":394863.27537199,"Y":137153.4794371,
                              "SE_ANNO_CAD_DATA":null}
                }, 
......'
 -- NOTE: This GeoJSON is truncated. 
 -- Copy full example from https://github.com/Esri/geojson-layer-js/blob/master/data/dc-bike-share.json

INSERT INTO BikeShare(position, ObjectId, Address, Bikes, Docks) 
SELECT geography::STGeomFromText('POINT ('+long + ' ' + lat + ')', 4326),
           ObjectId, Address, Bikes, Docks
from OPENJSON(@bikeShares, '$.features') 
        WITH (
           long varchar(100) '$.geometry.coordinates[0]',
           lat varchar(100) '$.geometry.coordinates[1]',
           ObjectId int '$.properties.OBJECTID',
           Address nvarchar(200) '$.properties.ADDRESS',
           Bikes int '$.properties.NUMBER_OF_BIKES',
           Docks int '$.properties.NUMBER_OF_EMPTY_DOCKS' )
```

I suggest to try **Option 2** first.

Note: Consider `Geography` instead of `Geometry` if you are using `GCS_WGS_1984` projection as is with Bing Maps.

Comment: Thanks guys, let me try it out and see which works for me

Answer (score 0):

Instead of retrieving GeoJSON from Bing Maps, retrieve Well Known Text: https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk/wktwritetowkt

Send this to your backend and then use the geometry::stgeomfromtext https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stgeomfromtext-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15

Note that DbGeometery will not support spatially accurate calculations. Consider storing the data as a DbGeograpgy instead using geography::stgeomfromtext https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stgeomfromtext-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15 and pass in '4326' as the SRID.

Comment: It worked like charm. Instead of getting GeoJSON, i retrieved Well Known Text from the Bing Maps using Javascript and then use DbGeometry.FromText(KnownText) on my C# controller;